# How to put insertion limit in MySQL database table entries according to certain condition?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way  to limit insertion in a database table? In the Student_Applications table, a certain Roll# cannot submit more than 6 applications? How will I do this in MySQL?
Let's say I want Student#1 to submit total of 4 applications while in the same table Student#2 can submit 6 applications?

Comment: How does a user insert data? Is it through a web based application?

Comment: @r0xette Not specifically. But if you know the solution from web based application point of view then do tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a web based application for example php based then you can do the following.

In your student_application table, there must be student_id. Before saving inserting your form entries into database, you can simply check COUNT(student_id) in student_application and if it is >= 6, instead of inserting the data you re-direct user to a page or show popup that user has exceeded limit of inserting applications.

Comment: I will try this. Thank You.

Comment: @mikaela01 Glad to help. If I satisfied your query, don't forget to click the check mark to accept the answer on the left of this post.